# Android - detect a BLE advertising

Tags: android

I would like to create a simple application:

- The user launches the application and the activity is displayed (displays text "no BLE device")
- The application scans permanently for BLE advertising
- The application displays the activity whenever it detects BLE advertising (displays "MAC address").

The BLE scan must run even if the activity loses the focus (in background).

Here are my questions :

1. Should I use the beacon library ? or just Android API?
2. Do you have any advice/recommendation for me? code example?

Thank you for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Android Beacon Library** (http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/). You will find all the sample code here and especially the monitoring code :

> http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you confirm me if the monitoring code runs if the activity loses the focus? For example I would like emit a "beep" even if android is in sleep mode.

Comment: Yes/No, you can do background tasks (notifications, web calls, ...). You can use a custom notification in order to achieve such things.

Comment: Even if I use Android L? Is the **Android Beacon Library** **Starting an App in the Background** a good solution?

Comment: I use Android L and my application works well. The smartphone vibrates for each advertising detected (with scancallback). My problem is that when the smartphone turns in standby mode, the application doesn't work. Do I have to create  a service ?

Comment: Go to http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html and see "Starting an App in the Background" sample.